# How to strip char 0x0 from the middle of a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, string-substitution

I am trying strip a 0x0 char i found in one of my files, when I discovered an xml parser was choking on it.

So I am use gsub:

`xmlBody.gsub!(/\u0000/i,'')`

to replace it. The xml parser is now satisfied. The xml file is then saved (w/ UTF-8 encoding).

However, when I re-open the file in Sublime text editor, Sublime crashes. And when I use another editor (that does not crash), and copy/paste the file's xml contents into an xml validator, the validator says char 0x0 is invalid. It seems gsub did not *really* remove the character.

Any suggestions?

I have also tried using force_encoding("UTF-8") for the xmlBody, and xmlBody.delete!(0x0) w/ same results.

Comment: I would open, replace and write back the file with regular File class, try to open in with ST, then open it with the xml parser

Comment: the xml comes from a rest service, and is written after the xml parse. But the first time the file is written, that 0x0 is in already in there. The source is a mongodb record with that bad char in there.

Comment: so you get an xml file with the 0x0, what do you need it after that ? surely not open it with ST ? too mutch info lacking iaa.
can you post a link to the service or a file with the problem ?

Comment: stripping the char again on the file write, took care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The xml actually comprises the file contents. I do strip out other characters and they are not in the file. But 0x0 kept coming back. So, I tried removing both on the xml parse (so it will parse correctly) and again on the file write. It finally went away.

`output.write(utf8_encoded_content.gsub!(/\u0000/i, ''))
 output.close`